# 3D tensor dataset with tensorflow Time series forecasting

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series

I am following the [tensorflow time series example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#baseline) but my data is slighlty different from the one presented in the example.

Instead of having a matrix representation of a time series I have a tensor.
That is, every matrix in the tensor is a time series of the same event in a different location, so I am keeping them all apart.

I was wondering how can I rewrite the code in a way that enables me to perform various model.fit on such tensor.

As for now my `make_dataset` function is the follwing:

```
 def make_dataset(self, data):
        dss = []
        for iso, df in data.items():
            df = df.drop('date', axis=1)
            data = np.array(df, dtype=np.float32)
            ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
                data=data,
                targets=None,
                sequence_length=self.total_window_size,
                sequence_stride=1,
                shuffle=True,
                batch_size=32, )

            ds = ds.map(self.split_window)
            dss.append(ds)
        return dss
```

Which return a list of MapDataset rater than a single one.

The actual error is raised in my `compile_and_fit` function taken from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#linear_model):

```
def compile_and_fit(model, window, patience=2, MAX_EPOCHS=20):
    early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                                                      patience=patience,
                                                      mode='min')

    model.compile(loss=tf.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
                  optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(),
                  metrics=[tf.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()])

    history = model.fit(window.train, epochs=MAX_EPOCHS,
                        validation_data=window.val,
                        callbacks=[early_stopping])
    return history
```

Where my model is a simple linear one:

```
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
    ])
```

Should I modify the `make_dataset` function or something in the `model`?
And how?

Comment: Apart from implementation... how do you want to *model* the different locations?

Comment: I don't think I understood your question, but if you are asking if I need one model for each location the answer is no. The same model should be trained on all the timestep of all the locations.